# CodeIgniter cache makes 2 files, one with errors and other right one - Why? What does this happen?

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I cache one page with CodeIgniter. And it creates two files in cache folder. One that is right, like it should be. And second one has many errors

`Message:  Trying to get property of non-object`

and

`Message:  Undefined offset: 0`

in lines where I get data send to this view like

`<?= $post[0]->data_dodania; ?>`

In browser I see the right one. Good cached page. without any errors. But in cache folder I get this two files, good one and bad one to the same page.

Why? What is this about?
Why cache is generating two files, bad and good one?

and code in Controller: PRINT SCREEN
[and code in Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE5r6.png)

Cache Files: PRINT SCREEN: [Cache Files: PRINT SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwZWz.png)

And what are these names? `93f498562c1788597009057fb11067eb`, `ec09f491c06d849fa4be87aaaca3c489` ? Why ? I thought it should be controller_name+function_name, not... something like this?
Files named like that without extension

Answer (score 0):

> And what are these names? 93f498562c1788597009057fb11067eb, ec09f491c06d849fa4be87aaaca3c489 ?

they are   hash  `md5($uri);` of your URI. so its similar to controllername+function name but in a hashed format. and there are not directly send to browser they are loaded into ci controller before sending. its not necessary to give  an extension. its not fully clear from your screenshot but try changing
`$this->output->cache(0.1);`
to something like

`$this->output->cache(10); // for 10 minute caching`

according to userguide

> $this->output->cache($n);
>
> Where $n is the number of **minutes** you wish the page to remain cached between refreshes.

so putting 0.1 there makes the cache valid for only 6 seconds. if you can add more code (not screenshot ) it might be useful for more accurate answering.

Comment: The code u just post has nothing to do with your problem. i think u did 2 requests . that may be lead to produce 2 cache in your directory. A page is cached based on uri .

Say you are  requesting a default controller ( welcome) , you can do it in 2 ways .

`http://site.name/welcome/index` and   `http://site.name/` . while caching they are considered as 2. so there will be 2 cache files.

so make sure that you are not making 2 requests

Comment: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIcHp.png` This is all the code. This is Main.php, and this is the default controller. My routes: `$route['default_controller'] = 'Main';
$route['(:any)'] = 'Main';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;` And that's just it.

Comment: Cache folder - empty. Only go to `index.php/przykladowy-tytul-strony` - 2 cache files generates, one bad one good. Deletes, Then go to only `przykladowy-tytul-strony` - Again, generated 2 cache files.

Comment: I found now that, this line in show_post function in Main controller may or not produce 2nd cache `$this->load->view('post', array('post' => $post, 'comments' => $comments, 'previous_next' => $previous_next));` If i cut it, only 1 file, if I add it back - 2 cache files. What is it about?

Comment: Lol dude, I found what is producing second file, lol. This line in view:`<img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" data-src="test2.jpg" alt="Przyładowe zdj artykułu" class="width-img"/>` And uri string inside this cache file (i echo'ed it) is test2.jpg

I do not understand it.... Like it create whole page for this single .jpg file... what?

Comment: I am sorry , i dont have enough knowledge about this . But i'm quite sure this is not the one that triggering the next request . its a base64 encoded image so there is no way this image causes the next request. but there might be another similar request that u might not noticed .

Comment: if this is the case ,  check the .htaceess , u can exclude direct directory and direct file access . add these lines before RewriteRule in .htaccess `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d `